# Остался ли в новой Android Studio функционал Initiate GC и Terminate Application?

Tags: android, android-studio

Недавно переехал на последнюю версию `Android Studio v3.1.2` c `v2.2.3`

Не могу найти следующий функционал:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Initiate GC
2. Terminate Application

Остался ли он в новом версии?

Если да, то где искать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Terminate Application` есть в LogCat (скрыт под шестерёнкой).
Вместо монитора теперь [Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler) и запуск GC есть в нём (кнопка 1 на [скрине](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#overview))

Comment: спасибо, все верно!